# How to set default value to a column on the basis of another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, default-value

I have two date columns in one table, i.e. onlineRegistrationCloseDate and onlineRegistrationFixesDate.  And for second date column I want to add one day to onlineRegistrationFixesDate column's value. Like if user has entered 2017-02-01 in **onlineRegistrationCloseDate** then automatically the date for **onlineRegistrationFixesDate** will be inserted as "2017-02-02".

I tried to set **Date_add(Select onlineRegistrationCloseDate , INTERVAL 1 DAY)** like this default value of second column but i am getting some error, I am using workbench for it.

Please help me how I can  set default value of second column on the based of first column's value.

Answer (score 1):

create BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

```
SET onlineRegistrationFixesDate = new.onlineRegistrationCloseDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: do i need to use trigger for it????????????

Comment: Yes, you do need to use a trigger, you cannot use an expression based on another column as a default value in MySQL, I'm not aware of an RDBMS that will let you do this without a trigger. You also only need to use one question mark.